# Telethon, how to get the profile of the one who is responded to?

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I define a message by text and it is a response to another message, how to get the id of the one who is responded to?

Comment: What do you mean with profile? If you want to get all data from that user, just use `client.get_entity(username)`.

Comment: @ClownDown i mean user id

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question with more details. What is your code, what did you try, and "who is who" in your scenario? Provide an example if possible. The advice in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will increase your chances of getting an useful answer.